# SQL query in MySQL is taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a problem with one query, this query is taking too long to find the records, sometimes it takes too long sending the data and sometimes sorting the results I'm talking about 10 to 20 seconds, this table isn't super big, I have bigger tables with millions of records, this table is small comparing to them

```
SELECT idFactura,
       strNombre,
       intFolio,
       CH_razon_social AS strRazonSocial,
       CH_nombre_comercial AS strNombreComercial,
       CH_RFC AS strRFC,
       doubleTotal,
       intTimbrada,
       intCancelada,
       dateFechaHora,
       intStatus,
       strSerie,
       email_enviado,
       strFolioFiscal,
       numero_abonos,
       saldoInsoluto_pagos,
       tipo_comprobante,
       strSerieParc
  FROM tbl_factura2
 WHERE dateFechaHora >= '2018-05-06'
   AND dateFechaHora <= '2018-06-06'
   AND intTimbrada = 1
   AND intCancelada = 0
   AND cfdi_33 = 1
   AND RFC_usuario = 'NUSN900420SS5'
   AND numero_abonos = 0
   AND (strFormaPago = 'PPD'
    OR strMetodoPago = '99')
 ORDER 
    BY idFactura DESC;
```

when I use the command `EXPLAIN` this is what I get and you can see that it is taking the `idx_compuesto7` index but sometimes it takes another, I know this depends on what `MySQL` is better for the query, I would like to know what can I change or another way to do this query to get a better performance, I know that the `OR` in the query could be a problem but I tried to do the query as two different to remove the `OR` but I got the same problem.

`*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tbl_factura2
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_fecha,idx_timbrada,idx_cancelada,idx_formaPago,idx_cfdi33,idx_rfc_usuario,idx_strMetodoPago,idx_compuesto3,idx_compuesto4,idx_compuesto5,idx_compuesto6,idx_compuesto7,idx_compuesto8,idx_compuesto9,idx_compuesto10,idx_compuesto11,idx_compuesto12
          key: idx_compuesto7
      key_len: 52
          ref: const
         rows: 40
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort`

as you can see the possible numbers of row are `40 records` but with this query when I run it I just get `1 record`, I don't know if this is acceptable or not considering the total number of records of the whole table

This is the definition of the whole indexes of this table

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name               | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tbl_factura2 |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | idFactura                 | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_contador            |            1 | idContador                | A         |        2248 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_fecha               |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_timbrada            |            1 | intTimbrada               | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_cancelada           |            1 | intCancelada              | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_contadorSub         |            1 | idContadorSub             | A         |         131 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_folio               |            1 | intFolio                  | A         |        1578 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_formaPago           |            1 | strFormaPago              | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_email_enviado       |            1 | email_enviado             | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_cfdi33              |            1 | cfdi_33                   | A         |          59 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_status              |            1 | intStatus                 | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_serie               |            1 | strSerie                  | A         |         538 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_rfc_usuario         |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |       17991 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_facturaexcel        |            1 | facturaExcel              | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_razonSocial         |            1 | CH_razon_social           | A         |       33734 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_nombreComercial     |            1 | CH_nombre_comercial       | A         |        2620 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_RFC                 |            1 | CH_RFC                    | A         |       67469 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_folio_fiscal        |            1 | strFolioFiscal            | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_saldoInsoluto       |            1 | saldoInsoluto_pagos       | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_tipo_comprobante    |            1 | tipo_comprobante          | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_existe_facprincipal |            1 | existe_facturaPrinc_pagos | A         |           5 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_strMetodoPago       |            1 | strMetodoPago             | A         |           7 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto1          |            1 | idFactura                 | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto1          |            2 | idContador                | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto1          |            3 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto2          |            1 | idContador                | A         |        2306 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto2          |            2 | cfdi_33                   | A         |        3551 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto3          |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto3          |            2 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto3          |            3 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto3          |            4 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto3          |            5 | RFC_usuario               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto4          |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |        4819 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto4          |            2 | intTimbrada               | A         |        5997 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto4          |            3 | intCancelada              | A         |        8705 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto4          |            4 | cfdi_33                   | A         |       11244 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto5          |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto5          |            2 | RFC_usuario               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto5          |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto5          |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto5          |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto6          |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |        3551 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto6          |            2 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto6          |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto6          |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto6          |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |        8995 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            2 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            6 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            7 | saldoInsoluto_pagos       | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto7          |            8 | tipo_comprobante          | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            2 | RFC_usuario               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            6 | strMetodoPago             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto8          |            7 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            2 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            3 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            4 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            5 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            6 | strFormaPago              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto9          |            7 | RFC_usuario               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            1 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            2 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            3 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            4 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            5 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            6 | strMetodoPago             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto10         |            7 | RFC_usuario               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |        3696 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            2 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            6 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto11         |            7 | strFormaPago              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            1 | RFC_usuario               | A         |       12851 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            2 | dateFechaHora             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            3 | intTimbrada               | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            4 | intCancelada              | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            5 | cfdi_33                   | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            6 | numero_abonos             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tbl_factura2 |          1 | idx_compuesto12         |            7 | strMetodoPago             | A         |      269877 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+--------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

For me the query is not taking the proper index or maybe I need to make another composite index to fix this.

This is the number of distinct values of the fields used in the query if this info is useful for someone, do you see something wrong with the info and the way the query was made? I hope you can help me to improve this, thank you.

`*************************** 1. row ***************************
count(distinct dateFechaHora): 260117
  count(distinct intTimbrada): 2
 count(distinct intCancelada): 2
      count(distinct cfdi_33): 2
  count(distinct RFC_usuario): 3621
count(distinct numero_abonos): 9
 count(distinct strFormaPago): 19
count(distinct strMetodoPago): 161
                total_records: 263320`

Comment: Too many conditions, though it should run faster.

Comment: index shotgun tactics.. index every column and hope MySQL will use it.. Besides indexing a query what contains a `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause requires multicolumn indexing and place the column that has the highest selectify first in the index.. Also might be faster to rewrite the OR part into a UNION ALL query.

Comment: Any index starting with `RFC_usuario` should be fine for this query, since there are only 73 (263320/3621) rows per value (on average). It's possible that it's the optimizer that takes so long to find a good index. Try to hide all indexes ([Invisible Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-indexes.html)) except of `idx_compuesto7` to see if that is the case.

Comment: The index `idx_compuesto7` seems to be optimal (or close to optimal at least). Now, if "sometimes it takes another", then force this index using `USING INDEX`, and see what do you get.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I will try this and I will tell you if this works, thanks.

Comment: @TheImpaler I tried this before and is the same result even when use the explain command, get the same info and same results.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel `ALTER INDEX` is for specific version of MySQL? I have 5.1 and this is not working `ALTER TABLE tbl_factura2 ALTER INDEX idx_contador INVISIBLE;` says syntax error.

Comment: Sorry.. that seems to be MySQL 8 feature. Then just copy the table to a dev server and drop the indexes.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I will do it

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I did it and obviously it takes only `idx_compuesto7` the info about `explain` is the same as I posted before but it is running faster but right now maybe because there arent many users using the webapp, I will check this again with high traffic to see if this worked or no, what about if you are right and the optimizer takes so long, there is a way to fix this? or just deleting indexes?

Comment: This is hard to say. I don't know why all those indexes exist. But I hardly believe that they all have been created for a good reason. Now you will need to investigate, which of them are really usefull. I can tell you that even `idx_compuesto7` doesn't make much sense. Only the first two columns seem to be usefull (Look at the `Cardinality` column, which doesn't change after the second column). Also many indexes will delay inserts and updates, locking rows for too long time, thus blocking select statements.

Comment: @TheImpaler - idx7 won't get past the second column - see my answer.

Comment: @TheImpaler - `USE/FORCE INDEX` may help to day, but may do the wrong thing tomorrow; try to avoid them.

Comment: @Fixer - `INVISIBLE` is a _very_ new feature.  Instead, you can try `IGNORE INDEX`.

Comment: @RickJames I'm with you. I meant it as a debug measure only.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Cardinality does not matter in a composite index.  It only matters when choosing between two different indexes.

Comment: @Fixer - `rows: 40` is only an estimate.  And it says that about 40 rows will result from the index.  `key_len:52` and `ref:const` say only one column is used; but this fails to include the `date` column.  So the first 2 columns will filter down to about 40 rows.

Comment: @RickJames - I can't agree with "*Cardinality does not matter in a composite index*". Though it doesn't matter in this case, because we have a range check on the second column of the index. But that doesn't make your comment correct.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - OK, my comment may not be precise enough.  Do you have an example of where cardinality does matter.

Comment: @RickJames - Concider an index on `(a,b,c)` while the combination of `(a,b)` is semi-unique (cardinality almost equals the number of rows). `c` in the index will unlikely improve any query, because after the equality checks on `a` and `b` only something like 1.01 rows (average) will be left. Now checking `c` in the index would be microoptimization and you could as good just lookup the value in the clustered index. So removing `c` from the index will be save in most cases. Extreme example: `idx_compuesto1(idFactura, idContador, cfdi_33)` PK as first column in the index.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - The first part of the comment makes sense; (1.01, so drop `c`). 
 Is the second part making a different point?  If idFactura is the PK of the InnoDB table it is in, then `(a)` is unique.  Then the _only_ reason to have that index (or the first 2 columns) is if it is "covering".

Comment: @RickJames - No it's not different - Just a special case (not just *semi-unique* - and redundant with the *clustered index*) and a real example from OPs schema. Might be used as *clustered index*, which is an overkill most of the time. There are also other cases where that makes sense (a PK prefixed index to "support" a compsite FK reference from a bigger table) - but they are rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1:  Get rid of any index that has columns *after* `dateFechaHora`.  When there is a range in the `WHERE`, the use of the index stops after testing for that column.

Step 2:  Get rid of `INDEX(a)` if you have `INDEX(a,b)`.  Extend this 'rule' to any prefix.

For *this particular* query, here is the optimal index:

```
INDEX(intTimbrada, intCancelada, cfdi_33, RFC_usuario, numero_abonos, -- in any order
      dateFechaHora)   -- last
```

See [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

As for removing the `OR`, this *may* help:

```
    (
        SELECT  ...
            FROM  tbl_factura2
            WHERE  ...
              AND  strFormaPago = 'PPD'
    )
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
        SELECT  ...
            FROM  tbl_factura2
            WHERE  ...
              AND  strMetodoPago = '99' 
    )
    ORDER BY  idFactura DESC;
```

plus these two indexes:

```
INDEX(intTimbrada, intCancelada, cfdi_33, RFC_usuario, numero_abonos, strFormaPago,
      dateFechaHora)   -- last
INDEX(intTimbrada, intCancelada, cfdi_33, RFC_usuario, numero_abonos, strMetodoPago,
      dateFechaHora)   -- last
```

As a rule:  If you have an `OR` getting in the way of operformance,

- Make 2 `SELECTs`, putting one side of the `OR` in each;
- Remove `ORDER BY` if present.  (`LIMIT` is more complex; not covered here.)
- Connect the `SELECTs` by `UNION ALL` if you are sure there is no overlap, or `UNION DISTINCT` (slower) if there could be dups.
- Use parens so that when you tack `ORDER BY` onto the end, it clearly belongs to the `UNION`, not the last `SELECT`.
- Make 2 new indexes according to the same rules in my Cookbook, one aimed at each `SELECT`.

But...  `UNION` has some overhead, so it may *or may not* speed up the query.  (I *guess* that it won't be beneficial for *this* query.)

Comment: I will try this also check the link and I will tell you what happened after do this, thanks for your answer.

Comment: This works perfectly, I didn't know that about the range, I will keep this in mind, do you explain this on your blog? thank you.

Comment: @Fixer - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#algorithm_step_2 plus 2a  (but you need to read the preceding paragraphs to understand them)

Comment: "Get rid of INDEX(a) if you have INDEX(a,b)" - You shouldn't forget that in *InnoDB* the PK will be appended to the index (if not explicitly part of it). So with `id` as PK `index(a)` is in fact `index(a, id)` and thus not a "prefix" of `index(a, b, [id])`. If you have `WHERE a = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 10` - `index(a)` can be used for both clauses, while `index(a, b)` can not be used for ORDER BY.

Comment: So for example when you told me to create this index `INDEX(intTimbrada, intCancelada, cfdi_33, RFC_usuario, numero_abonos, strFormaPago,
      dateFechaHora) ` really it looks like `INDEX(intTimbrada, intCancelada, cfdi_33, RFC_usuario, numero_abonos, strFormaPago,
      dateFechaHora, idFactura)`? that is why I don't need to add that column to the index even when the query says `ORDER BY idFactura DESC`?  or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Fixer - Yes: `idFactura` is the "invisible" part of the index. And No: It can't be used for ORDER BY in your query for multiple reasons. First - You can't use an index column if a column before has been used for a range check (As Rick also mentioned). Exception is a *covering index* which I wouldn't like to explain in this comment. Second reason: You can not use an index for ORDER BY if it is applied on a UNION query (at this point you are operationg on a temporary table where all indexes are (AFAIK) "lost").

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - True.  Read my `INDEX` as _not_ including `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY`.  The latter two have 'constraints' that would be lost.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Re `[id]` -- For that reason, I recommend explicitly including `id` at the end of an index when you need it for `WHERE/GROUP/ORDER`.  That is, for `WHERE a = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 10`, I would recommend explicitly saying `INDEX(a,id)`.  _Then_ go back to the rule that says "get rid of `INDEX(a)`".

Comment: (Hmmm... I should add a discussion about `[id]` to my blog.)

Comment: @Fixer - the "range" (namely the `date >= ...)` stops the use of the index for where/group/order.  The fact that `idFactura` is implicitly tacked on afterwards makes no difference to the Optimization.  If you _removed_ the date comparisons, _then_ the `ORDER BY` could be optimized.  Then index would need to have `date` _replaced_ by `id`.  You can't step over anything in the index.

Comment: Either way (`OR` or `UNION`), the same number of rows are being sorted by `idFactura`. And, as Paul says, no index will help _for the sorting_.

Comment: @RickJames - Re [id] -- I try to follow this convention (making the schema self documenting), but I might "forget" it :-) - 1. Create `INDEX(a)` for `WHERE a = ?`. 2. (months later) write query `MAX(id) .. WHERE a =?` - which runs fast, so you don't care. 3. (months later) Add `INDEX(a,b)` for another query. 4. (months later) Review the schema and find a "redundant" `INDEX(a)`. Now - drop it or not? I know, I should have changed `INDEX(a)` to `INDEX(a, id)` - but I didn't :-)